# Removing file extension from URL with Godaddy via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I am trying to remove php extension from URL, the php is removed but then the all php codes/file are not read when code is executed. Below is the code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php 
[NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)index$ $1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add below code in .htaccess file**

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule !.*.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

**Note : On Godaddy servers, In order to remove the extensions you need to enable MultiViews before. Below is the code for the same**

Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule !.*.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

Comment: The above code, does not remove php extension but the code works normally and php files works as usual

Comment: while calling the link  don't give the entire link. You have to specify the file name only and skip ".php" for eample if your link is http://www.domainname.com/home.php then specify only http://www.domainname.com/home

Comment: Cool bananas, it worked. Very kind of you to help me out. God bless